# Xamarin TapGestureRecognizer seems to be overly sensitive to 'micro swipes'

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a sensitivity to 'swiping' that can be set on Xamarin.Forms, at least for Android?  The problem I am experiencing is that I have to be extremely carefuly to literally 'tap' anything with a TapGestureRecognizer.

Any slight, slight deviation from a perfect tap seems to be interpreted as a swipe and ignored.

What is the recommended approach? Cover the element with both tap and swipe gesture recognizers? Is there any other solution?

Comment: could it work with below method ?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try to use CustomRenderer to define swiping events with **OnTouch** method:

here is an example for webview :

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Icu.Util;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;
using App18;
using App18.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;
using View = Android.Views.View;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>,View.IOnTouchListener
{
  private Context _context;
  private float preX;
  private float curX;
  public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
   {
    _context = context;
   }

  public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
   {
    if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
     {
        Toast.MakeText(_context, "click", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        preX = e.RawX;

     }

    if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
     {
        curX = e.RawX;
        //the distance you could define your own,here is 200,and just a simple judgment of the x direction
        if ((curX - preX) > 200)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(_context, "swipe right", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        if ((curX - preX) < -200)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(_context, "swipe left", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

     }
    return false;
  }

protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control == null)
    {
        var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
        SetNativeControl(webView);
        webView.LoadUrl("https://www.google.com");
        webView.SetOnTouchListener(this);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also use Pan gesture together with your Tap gesture and then check for total change in X and Y direction (e.g. if it is smaller than 10, execute your tap method).
Something like:

```
private void OnPan(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
       if(e.TotalX < 10 & e.TotalY < 10)
       {
             //call your tap
       }
}
```

And then you can add it like this to your element(I assumed you are using StackLayout):

```
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTap" />
        <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPan" />
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was unable to get either Pan or Swipe to work in combination with the Tap.